# Bernstein Inequality in Multi-Arms Bandits with Heavy Tails

Tags: probability, inequality

I was recently reading this paper: ["Bandits with heavy tail"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.1727.pdf).

In this paper, the authors have proved Lemma 1 using Bernstein's Inequality. I could not get that part of the paper.

First, the authors take the random variable

$$ \hat{\mu_{t}} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{t=1}^{n} X_{t} \mathbb{1}_{\left\{ |X_{t}| \leq \left(\frac{ut}{\log(\delta^{-1})}\right)^\frac{1}{1+\epsilon} \right\}}$$

and then they prove that with probability at least $1-\delta$,

$$\hat{\mu_{t}} < \mu + 4u^{\frac{1}{1+\epsilon}}\left(\frac{\log(\delta^{-1})}{n}\right)^{\frac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon}}$$

In the given proof I have three doubts,

1. Statment where Bernstein's Inequality is applied.
2. "It says an easy computation concludes the proof". I tried but could only simplify the last two terms out of three which is equal to 
   $(\sqrt{2} + \frac{1}{3})u^{\frac{1}{1+\epsilon}}(\frac{\log(\delta^{-1}}{n})^{\frac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon}}$. I could not simplify the first term of the last statement.
3. The statement "$E(X^{2}1_{|X \leq B|}) \leq uB^{1-\epsilon}$. I assume it to be some property of heavy tail distributions.

TIA.